# Banking app detects previous root

Tags: unrooting

I have a Sony xperia Z (C6603). A while back I rooted the device but then later I did a factory reset and unrooted it. Sadly I have forgotten exactly what software I used for rooting/unrooting.

Now the phone works perfectly for everything I do except for my Barclays Bank app which declares "Sorry, the Barclays Mobile Banking app does not support rooted devices".

I have tried mutilple root-detection utilities and they all insist the device is no  longer rooted.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: There is probably sime file left there, so only you can is to flash stock firmware

Comment: You can flash stock ROM. This'd be the best absolute solution. Because all other solutions would probably require you rooting the device again.

Answer (score 1):

If the App is using SafetyNet it also detects that your Bootloader is unlocked. So if your BL is still unlocked you will need to Lock it for the App to work.

I dont have a Xperia Z but this seems to explain how to do that:
[Link to xda](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-z/general/tutorial-relock-xperia-z-bootloader-t2191907)

- Download the latest Flashtool ( found in OG android development forum)
- Install the Flashtool drivers found in the drivers folder
- Connect phone in Flash-mode (phone shut down, volume down + power)
- Press the BLU button
- Press the relock option
- Put a stock .tft firmware in the Flashtool firmwares folder (this is required!!)
- Flash the firmware (this is required!!)
- Done

Answer (score 0):

Sure. There is some means.
You could check cydia, they propose a pack for hiding root (If I remember well the Barclays bank app is part of the app they provide by default).
You could also check that you really uninstalled root (by reinstalling stock recovery): did you go through this?
The last and ultimate step would be to delete /data/app*/<root-app-package>, /data/data/<root-app-package> and /sdcard/Android/data/<root-app-package>. But you need to be root to do that :)